# Is there any android epub reader supporting epub3 with audio/video/javascript?

Tags: ebook-reader, epub

Hi i just developed an epub format ebook (containing a video and a javascript animation).It is working fine on iphone/ipad (running on ibooks)..I was wondering if I could read the same ebook with an Android phone/tablet ?

Comment: Might keep an eye on [this thread](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=170973) to see if anyone answers there.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Infinity Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imeonsoft.infinity). It supports audio, video and all ePub3 features. The reader comes with a free book, which contains youtube video. Moreover, you can download a lot of free books.

Answer (score 1):

From Android Play Store, you can use [ASTRI-Bee (full version)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.astri.mmct.astribee&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5hc3RyaS5tbWN0LmFzdHJpYmVlIl0.):

> 1. **Support for epub3 ebooks**, e.g. the RTL epub books which is generally not available for reading in most of the epub readers but a basic feature of epub3 ebooks, also **javascript within epub ebooks is enabled**.
>      Also support pdf, txt, html formatted ebooks.
> 2. **Support for audio and video content within the epub ebooks**, again, this is just a basic feature of epub3 ebooks, but we also extend the support of multimedia to epub2 ebooks using the adobe flash plugin(requiring that the adobe flash preinstalled on your device)

<sup>I've highlighted what concerns your question.</sup>

**Ps:** Appears to be a "young app"... only one revision.

Answer (score 1):

[Kobo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kobobooks.android) seems to be your best bet, and [Gyan](http://www.handster.com/gyan_epub_reader.html) looks like it could work too.

Here's a couple others, but they are low-rated or in beta, so use at your own risk.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vitalsource.bookshelf

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.easyaccess.epubreader

Source: http://www.mathjax.org/resources/epub-readers/

Answer (score 0):

From the description in the Market, take a look @ Himawari - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.green_fld.himawari

Although the reviews aren't altogether too favourable.

Also, Ibis Reader has recently introduced the epub3 format into its reader - http://epub3.ibisreader.com/

Comment: thanks.any opensource classes i could use to read epub 3.0 on android devices as well?

Comment: @luca for the Class, check out the [github: epublib by psiegman](https://github.com/psiegman/epublib/) and there also [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5640728/352449) .

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [Gyan ePub Reader](http://www.handster.com/gyan_epub_reader.html). It is a fully compliant epub3 reader with audio and video support.

No Adobe plugins are required. It renders maths equations, SVG animations and has a read-aloud feature.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note that [if you are affiliated to the mentioned app you are required to mention this in your post](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)

Answer (score 0):

SkyEpub definitely supports epub3 (audio/video media overlay functions)
See this link [enter link description here](http://skyepub.net)